# is it possible to show all position in table of referenced model with REST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rails-activerecord

I have two models, one is User, and second is Lot, my user model **has_many** Lots. REST gives me index action to display all instances of Lot class of a specific User, but does it have an action to display all lots of all users, or should i make a custom action?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve it with [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: yes, but it's not exactly what i wanted, your way is by calling all users and then call all their lots, but my idea is index all lots in lots_controller.rb without any calls to users and it's all with REST and stuff!

Comment: @PaulBe I've change my answer

Comment: yes, i've seen that, but it's not what i need, there's no action wich will be produce /lots url (it is what i need), if Lots nested in Users, there will be user_id/lots in index action anyway, so now i see there's only way: to make a custom action and then just make some changes in routes

Comment: you can have it in your `lots#index`. You'll have `@lots = Lot.all` instead of `@lots = Lot.where(user: user)`. You'll have to update your `routes` adding `resources :lots, only: :index` and it's done! :)